# JAXB Xml Namespace only to few fields

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How to pragmatically read an xml like this using JAXB? Tried doing this but doesn't work as all the namespaces are listing under Root element [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm0F4.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event xmlns="http://www.test.com/test1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <header>
      <eventname>tgtsrequest</eventname>     
   </header>
   <p:node xmlns:p="http://www.test.com/test2">
      <p:name>
         <p:firstname>Joe</p:firstname>        
      </p:name>
   </p:node>  
</event>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If you have code, please share

Comment: Added an image of code i tried

Comment: Add the actual code here.  Images of code aren't particularly helpful, especially externally held images.